# javascript input field get cleared when page postback

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, vb.net

I am Working With VB ASP.net and  back End as SQL in That I have To Choose date From Calendar for that I Used javaScript calendar as client Side Coding and other Controls , when my page get postback I lost the calendar value which I was selected but I have to keep the date till I click the save Button here is that TextBox Input

```
<input name="txtpodate" id="inputField00" type="text"  
                      style="width:28px; font-family:Segoe UI; font-size:14pt; height: 20pt; background-color: #3366FF;" 
                       onclick ="a();" />
```

I have Used Hidden Field , onblur , onFocus events but its not Working,

the calendar function is

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="jsDatePick_ltr.min.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="jsDatePick.min.1.3.js" ></script>

 <script type="text/javascript" id ="calender">

        function setCurrentDate() {

            var d = new Date();
            var month = new Array();
            month[0] = "JAN";
            month[1] = "FEB";
            month[2] = "MAR";
            month[3] = "APR";
            month[4] = "MAY";
            month[5] = "JUN";
            month[6] = "JUL";
            month[7] = "AUG";
            month[8] = "SEP";
            month[9] = "OCT";
            month[10] = "NOW";
            month[11] = "DEC";

            var mnth = month[d.getMonth()];
            var convertedStartDate = new Date();
            var day = convertedStartDate.getDate();
            var year = convertedStartDate.getFullYear();
            var shortStartDate = day + "-" + mnth + "-" + year;

           document.getElementById("inputField00").text = shortStartDate;
           document.getElementById("inputField").value = shortStartDate;
           document.getElementById("inputField0").value = shortStartDate;


        }


function a() {

            new JsDatePick({
                useMode: 2,
                target: "inputField00",
                dateFormat: "%d-%M-%Y"


            });

            new JsDatePick({
                useMode: 2,
                target: "inputField",
                dateFormat: "%d-%M-%Y"

            });
            new JsDatePick({
                useMode: 2,
                target: "inputField0",
                dateFormat: "%d-%M-%Y"

            });

            setCurrentDate();

        };


      </script>            
    </asp:Content>
```

can somebody Help me?

Comment: Consider using the asp.net Calendar control instead. :)

Comment: Thanks Lim, But The asp.net Calendar is too large it occupies too many space .can I use calendar in onclick event like a pop, It Is possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

modify your input tag as below to add runat=server

```
<input runat="server" name="txtpodate" id="inputField00" type="text"  
                      style="width:28px; font-family:Segoe UI; font-size:14pt; height: 20pt; background-color: #3366FF;" 
                       onclick ="a();" />
```

then edit the script to get the new generated clientID from the input field

in

```
document.getElementById("<%= inputField00.ClientID  %>").text = shortStartDate;
```

and

```
new JsDatePick({
                useMode: 2,
                target: "<%= inputField00.ClientID  %>",
                dateFormat: "%d-%M-%Y"
            });
```

Comment: if I put runat="server" means it is not showing the calendar

Comment: check the edited answer, I forgt to change the code inside a() function too.

Comment: This Is the Final Code<input name="txtpodate" id="inputField00" runat="server" type="text" 
                      style="width:111px; font-family:Segoe UI; font-size:14pt; height: 20pt; background-color:White;" 
                       onclick =" return a();" />

Answer (score 1):

add runat="server" to your input!

Comment: If I Put runat="server" it's not showing the calendar

Comment: Could you elaborate your answer a bit more?

Comment: for the value to be passed to the server he op needs to add runat="server" to the input field, without this the data won't be sent to the server and there is no way for it to be present after post back. This is the logical first place to look.

Answer (score 1):

HTML form fields,by default,do not maintain their state after a postback because HTTP is stateless. What you can do is create a hidden value (which you have tried) and set its value from C#. In Javascript in your document load,check whether hidden field has value, if yes set the calendar to it otherwise do nothing.

1. Add a hidden field in you .aspx page:

   ```
   <asp:HiddenField ID="hidden" runat="server" />
   ```
2. Change the value of this field in your code-behind:

   ```
      protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
      hidden.Value = CurrentDate;
      }
   ```
3. Write the following script to access the value and put it in any variable:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
       if (document.getElementById("MainContent_hidden") != undefined) {
           var hiddenVal = document.getElementById("MainContent_hidden").value;
           document.getElementById("inputField00").text = hiddenVal;
           document.getElementById("inputField").value = hiddenVal;
           document.getElementById("inputField0").value = hiddenVal;
       }
   ```

Comment: Thanks Ash,I don't know how to set calendar value from code behind i tried Response.Write("txtpodate") But its not Working , Do You Have any idea about this ?

Comment: i have created a hidden field like <input name="Hidden1" id="Hidden1" type ="hidden" runat ="server"  /> and I am Working In VB so in page load i added Hidden1.Value = DateTime.Today() and in source code side i addad   if (document.getElementById("Hidden1") != undefined)
             {
                 var hiddenVal = document.getElementById("Hidden1").value;
                document.getElementById("inputField00").text = hiddenVal;
                document.getElementById("inputField").value = hiddenVal;
                document.getElementById("inputField0").value = hiddenVal;
             }

Comment: No Also I want to save the date selected by User

Comment: <input name="Hidden1" id="Hidden1" type ="hidden" runat ="server" /> and I am Working In VB so in page load i added Hidden1.Value = DateTime.Today() and in source code side i addad if (document.getElementById("Hidden1") != undefined) { var hiddenVal = document.getElementById("Hidden1").value; document.getElementById("inputField00").text = hiddenVal; document.getElementById("inputField").value = hiddenVal; document.getElementById("inputField0").value = hiddenVal; }

Answer (score 0):

Try overridding your pageLoad event like this in your markup.

```
function pageLoad(sender, args)
     {
      setCurrentDate();

     }
```

This will reset the date after the post back.Let me know if this works.